# Java problem: Need a sorted JList to represent a database table

Tags: java, database, swing, sorting, jlist

I've found a [sample](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/sorted_jlist/) for a sorted JList, but my application is powered by an embedded H2 database so I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to implement this with that in mind.  Especially considering the table in question could become enormously large, and duplicating all that data in a JList's list model seems to kinda defeat the point of having a database to manage it.

Is there a good way to do this?  Or am I forced to cobble together some clumsy hack to allow the JList to "scroll" through dynamically queried chunks of data or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JList`'s `ListModel` is responsible for exposing the backing data as an ordered list. *`ListModel`'s methods will be called by `JList` from the UI (AWT event) thread, so its performance needs to be pretty good.* This is why most implementations have the `ListModel`'s backing data in memory. I suppose you could implement `ListModel` with your database as the backing data. You'll most likely extend `AbstractListModel` to get the listener registration, and implement `getElementAt(int)` and `getSize()`. `getElementAt` would then be responsible for getting the object for a particular index. Keep in mind that `JList` will call `getElementAt` many times for different indices, so you may find yourself caching the results. Depending on how much data you're caching, you might just retrieve the entire dataset from the database.